# how to use "is characteristic with"

Tags: adjectives

The tongue **is characteristic with** yellow coating at the base, or it may be dry, smooth, glazed and cracked.

X **is characteristic with** y

I cannot get the concept of the bold parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrasing is sometimes used to mean that *x* is a defining feature or way to identify something (in this case, presumably a disease), with your *y* giving details.  You could also think of this as:

> Yellow coating at the base of the tongue is characteristic, or it (the
>   tongue) may be dry, smooth, glazed and cracked.

It is quite common with medical descriptions for *x* to be some sort of diagnostic procedure:

> The histology is characteristic, with...